# Allow only specific letters in specific column in RadGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik, keypress

I have a RadGridView, i want to prevent the user from writing any characters or digits or letters other than 'c' or 'd' in the **fifth** column.
I have tried the below code, but it did not work...

```
private void radGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (radGridView1.CurrentColumn.Index == 4)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar != 'c' || e.KeyChar != 'd' )
             e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code snippet, if you wish to do anything more such as alert the user, or add a validation error, that's up to you:

```
     private void radGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, CellValidatingEventArgs e)
     {
        String[] Acceptable = new string[] {"c", "d"};

        if (e.Value != null && e.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            if(e.Value != e.OldValue)
            {
                if (!Acceptable.Contains(e.Value))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @fadddd If it worked, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer to let future users know it worked for you :)